# Response issue with callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, callback

I think I'm missing something simple here but think that I've been looking at this too long.

I originally had what you see here in the function inline, but would like to pull it out and use it in other aspects of my app, but I can't seem to get the intended information into the POST response.

Here's my function:

```
let lookUpUserId = (x) => {
  mongo.connect(url, (err,db) => {
    assert.equal(null,err);
    db.collection('data').findOne({"email": {'$eq' : x }},{"_id":1}, (err,result) => {
      console.log(result); // I'm getting the correct response here.
      assert.equal(null,err);
      db.close();
      return result; // This seems to be returning empty
    });
  });
};
```

And now here's where I'm calling it (simplified):

```
router.post('/test1', (req,res,next) => {
    console.log('Hit on POST /test1');
    let obj = 'email@email.com';
    let a = lookUpUserId(obj);
    res.send(a);
});
```

Now in the server's console I'm getting the expected info:

```
{_id:someIdHere }
```

However, I'm getting an empty body in response to my POST on the client side.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lookUpUserId` works asynchronously. Since you're not using promises, you can pass a callback as a second argument of `lookUpUserId` function:

```
let lookUpUserId = (x, callback) => {
  mongo.connect(url, (err,db) => {
    assert.equal(null,err);
    db.collection('data').findOne({"email": {'$eq' : x }},{"_id":1}, (err,result) => {
      console.log(result);
      assert.equal(null,err);
      db.close();
      callback(result);
    });
  });
};
```

and call it with:

```
lookUpUserId(obj, (result) => res.send(result));
```

or even:

```
lookUpUserId(obj, res.send);
```

Comment: Tried both solutions here, first one works perfectly though I wasn't able to get the shorthand version to work properly as it was through a 'req was undefined'. Either way, solved.

Comment: @Gates `req was undefined` ? I didn't even use `req` here.

Comment: yeah I'm not really sure, probably something todo with how I've setup router. I'll dig into it.